# Why is it throwing if I'm using a reference to struct?

Tags: rust, actix-web

I'm using this code and I don't understand how to fix this error:

```rust
use custom::config;

use actix_web::{web, App, HttpResponse, HttpServer};

pub async fn start(config: &'static config::Config) -> std::io::Result<()> {
    return HttpServer::new(move || {
        let mut app = App::new();

        if config.custom_enabled {
            app = app.route("/custom", web::get().to(HttpResponse::Ok))
        }

        app = app.route("/", web::get().to(HttpResponse::Ok));

        return app;
    })
    .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?
    .run()
    .await;
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let config = config::new();

    server::start(&config).await; // throws here
}
```

throws with:

```
`config` does not live long enough
borrowed value does not live long enough rustc E0597
```

Why?

Comment: There is no way it throws; there are no exceptions in Rust.

Answer (score 2):

Yes as compiler says: `config does not live enough`. When you pass config to async function `start` in this case, it cannot be guranteed weather the parent thread long enough as long the async part does.

In the code you given, `main` exits just right after triggering the `start`, Until main exits, `start` may or may not have been completed so it cannot be guaranteed.

> But if main is closed everything is closed! Nope?

Well no guaranteed. Async runtime may manage itself within one single thread or multiple thread as per required or per configuration. And as this is not guaranteed by the async runtime, you async code might be closed with main or it may not. Talking about if it swapns another thread, it can be externally configured as per os to kill or not kill the child thread if parent is killed. So these inconsistent behavior will have to be respected by compiler and it cannot make any assumption about such.

Comment: But if main is closed everything is closed! Nope?

Comment: I tried to elaborate in original answer :)

Comment: In fact, that would be incorrect even without async code. First, `main` is a normal function, and - from the compiler's point of view - it can be called as a normal function, not as an entry point. Second, it _is_ called like a normal function, even when it's an entrypoint - here in stdlib: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/a9ca1ec9280ca1e5020edd699917c3367a30a798/src/libstd/rt.rs#L52.

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't see config was receiving `&'static` thanks for correction